# C# EF Core OUTER APPLY with TOP 1 and LEFT JOIN

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Here is an example of a database structure (which I can't change).

**Database Diagram :**

[image]

```sql
create table [MarketingData] (
    [MaterialNumber] int not null,
    [Language] char(2) not null,
    [Data] nvarchar(50) null,

    constraint [PK_MarketingData] primary key clustered ([MaterialNumber], [Language])
)
go

create table [Material] (
    [MaterialNumber] int not null,
    [Language] char(2) not null,
    [CountryOfOrigin] nvarchar(50) not null,
    [MaterialDetailId] int null,

    constraint [PK_Material] primary key clustered ([MaterialNumber], [Language], [CountryOfOrigin])
)
go

create table [MaterialDetail] (
    [Id] int not null identity(1,1),
    [Detail] nvarchar(50) null,

    constraint [PK_MaterialDetail] primary key clustered ([Id])
)
go

set identity_insert [MaterialDetail] on
go

insert into [MaterialDetail] ([Id], [Detail])
values (1, 'detail of material 123');

set identity_insert [MaterialDetail] off
go

insert into [Material] ([MaterialNumber], [Language], [CountryOfOrigin], [MaterialDetailId])
values (123, 'EN', 'GB', 1), (123, 'EN', 'US', 1)
go

insert into [MarketingData] ([MaterialNumber], [Language], [Data])
values (123, 'EN', 'marketing data of material 123')
go
```

**I need to select MarketingData with MaterialDetail. Problem is that key to MaterialDetail is in another table Material, where same material with same number is more than once.**

This is the query I would like EF to generate.

```sql
select * 
from [MarketingData] mark
outer apply (
    select top 1 m.[MaterialNumber], m.[Language], m.[CountryOfOrigin], m.[MaterialDetailId]
    from [Material] m
    where m.[MaterialNumber] = mark.[MaterialNumber]
        and m.[Language] = mark.[Language]
) material
left join [MaterialDetail] det 
    on det.Id = material.MaterialDetailId
```

Can you please advise me how to write a EF Core 6 query (method based ideally)?

this is my attempt which resulted in inefficient SQL.

```cs
var data = await context.MarketingData
    .Select(mark => new //Outer apply top 1 material
    {
        MarketingData = mark,
        Material = context.Materials.FirstOrDefault(mat => mat.MaterialNumber == mark.MaterialNumber && mat.Language == mark.Language)
    })
    .GroupJoin(context.MaterialDetails, //Left join material detail
        markMat => markMat.Material.MaterialDetailId,
        det => det.Id,
        (markMat, group) => new { markMat.MarketingData, markMat.Material, Details = group })
    .SelectMany(o => o.Details.DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (markMat, det) => new { markMat.MarketingData, markMat.Material, MaterialDetail = det })
    .ToListAsync();
```

Translation of query above

```sql
SELECT [m].[MaterialNumber], [m].[Language], [m].[Data], [m0].[Id], [m0].[Detail], [t0].[MaterialNumber], [t0].[Language], [t0].[CountryOfOrigin], [t0].[MaterialDetailId]
      FROM [MarketingData] AS [m]
      LEFT JOIN [MaterialDetail] AS [m0] ON (
          SELECT TOP(1) [m1].[MaterialDetailId]
          FROM [Material] AS [m1]
          WHERE ([m1].[MaterialNumber] = [m].[MaterialNumber]) AND ([m1].[Language] = [m].[Language])) = [m0].[Id]
      LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT [t].[MaterialNumber], [t].[Language], [t].[CountryOfOrigin], [t].[MaterialDetailId]
          FROM (
              SELECT [m2].[MaterialNumber], [m2].[Language], [m2].[CountryOfOrigin], [m2].[MaterialDetailId], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [m2].[MaterialNumber], [m2].[Language] ORDER BY [m2].[MaterialNumber], [m2].[Language], [m2].[CountryOfOrigin]) AS [row]
              FROM [Material] AS [m2]
          ) AS [t]
          WHERE [t].[row] <= 1
      ) AS [t0] ON ([m].[MaterialNumber] = [t0].[MaterialNumber]) AND ([m].[Language] = [t0].[Language])
```

Comment: When I see *method based ideally*,  my hands stop writing answer. It is a pain writing using method syntax query which uses several tables. Also instead of posting tables definition, update question with model. LINQ Query is built from classes and their navigation properties.

Comment: EF will let you send raw SQL. I suggest you use that ability.